# Concurrent.futures.map initializes code from beginning

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I am a fairly beginner programmer with python and in general with not that much experience, and currently I'm trying to parallelize a process that is heavily CPU bound in my code. I'm using anaconda to create environments and Visual Code to debug.
A summary of the code is as following :

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import myfuncs as mf, concurrent.futures
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename('Ask for a file containing data')
# import data from file_path
a = input('Ask the user for input')
```

Next calculations are made from these and I reach a stage where I need to iterate of a list of lists. These lists may contain up to two values and calls are made to a separate file.

For example the inputs are :

```
sub_data1 = [test1]
sub_data2 = [test1, test2]
dataset = [sub_data1, sub_data2]
```

This is the stage I use **`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`**-instance and its **`.map()`** method :

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   sm_res = executor.map(mf.process_distr, dataset)
```

While inside a `myfuncs.py`, the `mf.process_distr()` function works like this :

```
def process_distr(tests):
    sm_reg = []
    for i in range(len(tests)):                
        if i==0:
            # do stuff
            sm_reg.append(result1)
        else:
            # do stuff
            sm_reg.append(result2)
    return sm_reg
```

The problem is that when I try to execute this code on the `main.py` file, it seems that the `main.py` starts running multiple times, and asks for user inputs and file dialog pops up multiple times (same amount as cores count).

How can I resolve this matter?

**Edit**: After reading more into it, encapsulating the whole main.py code with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**did the trick.** Thank you to anyone who gave time to help with my rookie problem.

Comment: Welcome, Steve, it would be nice to post the full, reproducible ( yes, with some mock-up small-scale data too ) MCVE-code to re-run your claimed problem. This is how StackOverflow works, so do not hesitate to comply with the Community Site Rules.